# Using multiple versions of a Yeoman Generator on the same machine

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Once a project has been scaffolded by a Yeoman generator, using future releases of the generator that was used can break the code in the project.  Is it possible to have multiple versions of a generator on one's machine, and specify which version Yeoman is to use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is effectively a node module, so yes, you could npm install with a specific version, and or rename them to your requirements